# Изображение в матрицу

Tags: c++, изображения

Ребят помогите с задачей, нужно взять изображение и перевести его в чёрное белое в виде матрицы 0 или 1, или как яркость вроде. Какие библиотеки возможно использовать? Или можно воспользоваться стандартными средствами тип fstream. Подскажите в какую сторону копать или можете скинуть статьи на данную тему

Comment: Попробуйте opencv

Comment: Зависит от того, в каком виде у вас изображение. Расписывать ответы под все возможные варианты - не вариант

Comment: Копать нужно в сторону "бинаризация изображений".  Посмотрите в сторону netpbm -- там реализовано несколько разных алгоритмов бинаризации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться как старой, но проверенной `graphics.h`, так и фреймворком `Qt`. В обоих случаях можно узнать цвет пикселя, а это самое главное. Определив цвет, принимаем решение - темный пиксель или нет, соответственно сделав нужный элемент числового массива нулем или единицей. Скорее всего, придется использовать либо тот же самый `Qt`, либо, к примеру, `ImageMagic`. Удачи!